# How to solve extrinsic function error?

Tags: matlab

I use in a function:

```
 STDinputs(nset1,nimp1)=nanstd(inputstemp,0,2);

   AVinputs(nset1,nimp1)=nanmean(inputstemp,2);
```

inputstemp size is (100,33,2000);

This 2 lines works very well in Matlab code but when I try to compile 
mex file using :

```
coder.extrinsic('nanstd','nanmean');
```

compiler return this error:

> "MATLAB expression 'nanstd' is not of the correct size: expected
>   [100x2000] found [100x1x2000]."

What's wrong?

I use "codegen" in this modality:

```
cfg=coder.config; 
cfg.ResponsivenessChecks = false; 
cfg.ExtrinsicCalls = true; 
cfg.IntegrityChecks = false; 
cfg.SaturateOnIntegerOverflow = false;
codegen -config cfg OPTIM2_GeneticPattern -args {zeros(100,82,'double')};
```

I want to import nanstd & nanmean in a mex file but size of imputstemp is not recognized well and it return an error.

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: I use "codegen" in this modality:                                                           cfg=coder.config;                                                                                      
cfg.ResponsivenessChecks = false; 
cfg.ExtrinsicCalls = true; cfg.IntegrityChecks = false;
cfg.SaturateOnIntegerOverflow = false;codegen -config  cfg OPTIM2_GeneticPattern -args {zeros(100,82,'double')};                                                                           I want to import nanstd & nanmean in a mex file but size of imputstemp is not recognized well and it return an error.

Comment: Please edit the question adding these details.